# Algorithms with superexponential runtime?

Tags: regex, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, satisfiability

I was talking with a student the other day about the common complexity classes of algorithms, like O(n), O(n<sup>k</sup>), O(n lg n), O(2<sup>n</sup>), O(n!), etc.  I was trying to come up with an example of a problem for which solutions whose best known runtime is super-exponential, such as O(2<sup>2<sup>n</sup></sup>), but still decidable (e.g. not the halting problem!)  The only example I know of is [satisfiability of Presburger arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presburger_arithmetic), which I don't think any intro CS students would really understand or be able to relate to.

My question is whether there is a well-known problem whose best known solution has runtime that is superexponential; at least ω(n!) or ω(n<sup>n</sup>).  I would really hope that there is some "reasonable" problem meeting this description, but I'm not aware of any.

Comment: Interesting question. Going beyond that: is there any program which is guaranteed to terminate for any finite combination of input symbols, but whose worst-case time and space requirements for a given input size cannot be computed in bounded time?  Note that restricting the question to "any valid input" would render the question meaningless: if the validity of input can be determined in valid time, then termination would be guaranteed for all inputs; if it can't, then any *undecidable* problem would complete for those inputs where it completes and wouldn't for those where it doesn't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Maximum Parsimony](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_parsimony_%28phylogenetics%29) is the problem of finding an evolutionary tree connecting n DNA sequences (representing species) that requires the fewest single-nucleotide mutations.  The n given sequences are constrained to appear at the leaves; the tree topology and the sequences at internal nodes are what we get to choose.

**In more CS terms:** We are given a bunch of length-k strings that must appear at the leaves of some tree, and we have to choose a tree, plus a length-k string for each internal node in the tree, so as to minimise the sum of [Hamming distances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) across all edges.

When a fixed tree is also given, the optimal assignment of sequences to internal nodes can be determined very efficiently using the [Fitch algorithm](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/labs/beta/Courses/CPSC536A-01/Class10/class10-notes.html).  But in the usual case, a tree is not given (i.e. we are asked to *find* the optimal tree), and this makes the problem NP-hard, meaning that every tree must in principle be tried.  Even though an evolutionary tree has a root (representing the hypothetical ancestor), we only need to consider distinct unrooted trees, since the minimum number of mutations required is not affected by the position of the root.  For n species there are 3 * 5 * 7 * ... * (2n-5) leaf-labelled unrooted binary trees.  (There is just one such tree with 3 species, which has a single internal vertex and 3 edges; the 4th species can be inserted at any of the 3 edges to produce a distinct 5-edge tree; the 5th species can be inserted at any of these 5 edges, and so on -- this process generates all trees exactly once.)  This is sometimes written **(2n-5)!!**, with !! meaning "double factorial".

In practice, branch and bound is used, and on most real datasets this manages to avoid evaluating most trees.  But highly "non-treelike" random data requires all, or almost all (2n-5)!! trees to be examined -- since in this case many trees have nearly equal minimum mutation counts.

Comment: @j_random_hacker- My understanding is that n!! < n!, since double-factorial means n(n-2)(n-4)...(1), rather than (n!)!.  Is this incorrect?

Comment: You're right.  But bear in mind that there is a 2n (rather than just an n) under the double factorial sign for this problem, and (2n)!! > n! for all n > 0.  Actually I'm not sure what the tightest "canonical" big-O complexity measure for this is.

Comment: @j_random_hacker- I think a "canonical" big-O for this would be O(2^n n!), since each term of the double-factorial is just over twice as large as its counterpart in the regular factorial and there's n of them.  This looks like a great answer; thanks for posting it!

Comment: Thanks!  Your big-O expression looks dead-on to me.

Answer (score 7):

Showing all permutation of string of length n is n!, finding Hamiltonian cycle is n!, minimum graph coloring, ....

**Edit**: even faster [Ackerman functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function). In fact they seems without bound function.

```
A(x,y) = y+1 (if x = 0)
A(x,y) = A(x-1,1) (if y=0)
A(x,y) = A(x-1, A(x,y-1)) otherwise.

from wiki:
A(4,3) = 2^2^65536,...
```

Comment: All permutations runs in O(n n!), as does finding a Hamiltonian cycle.  This is indeed w(n!), but what I was hoping for was something even faster-growing than this.  Thanks for posting this, though; you're absolutely right!

Comment: Hamilton cycle and graph coloring have exponential time DPs.

Comment: @user635541, I don't know any exponential time DP for HC ( and I think there isn't), but if there is, it's big enough, Also After OP wants better example I suggest ackerman function.

Comment: @user635541, yes you are right, HC can have a simple DP with running time 2^n*poly(n) and may be there are even better algorithms by use of graph decompositions.

Answer (score 5):

Do algorithms to compute real numbers to a certain precision count? The formula for the area of the Mandelbrot set [converges extremely slowly](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MandelbrotSet.html); 10<sup>118</sup> terms for two digits, 10<sup>1181</sup> terms for three.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a practical everyday problem, but it's a way to construct relatively straightforward problems of increasing complexity.

- The Kolmogorov complexity K(x) is the size of the smallest program that outputs the string $x$ on a pre-determined universal computer U. It's easy to show that most strings cannot be compressed at all (since there are more strings of length n than programs of length n).
- If we give U a maximum running time (say some polynomial function P), we get a time-bounded Kolmogorov complexity. The same counting argument holds: there are some strings that are incompressible under this time bounded Kolmogorov complexity. Let's call the first such string (of some length n) x<sub>P</sub>
- Since the time-bounded Kolmogorov complexity is computable, we can test all strings, and find x<sub>P</sub>
- Finding x<sub>P</sub> can't be done in polynomial time, or we could use this algorithm to compress it, so finding it must be a super-polynomial problem. We do know we can find it in exp(P) time, though. (Jumping over some technical details here)
- So now we have a time-bound E = exp(P). We can repeat the procedure to find x<sub>E</sub>, and so on.

This approach gives us a decidable super-F problem for every time-constructible function F: find the first string of length n (some large constant) that is incompressible under time-bound F.

Answer (score 1):

Two elementary results in the conversion of regular expressions of complements of regular languages involve truly superexponential runtime. See this [Computer Science question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/99605/is-super-exponential-a-precise-definition-of-algorithmic-complexity) for more details.

### The definition of 'superexponential'

There are various differeing definitions of exponential time.

1. The most restrictive definition defines exponential time as being upper bounded by a *simple exponential function* `B`<sup>`x`</sup> for some `B > 1`. This defines the **E** complexity class.
2. The most conventional definition, **EXPTIME**, consists of all algorithms with runtime requiring only a *single exponent* to express. Namely, it is of the form `B`<sup>`g(x)`</sup> where `g` is polynomial in `x`. Polynomials do not require any exponents to express.

   - Factorial time `n!`, which asymptotically dominates any simple exponential function, is bounded above by `n`<sup>`n`</sup>, which can be converted to `e`<sup>`n ln n`</sup>. Therefore, the expression `n`<sup>`n`</sup> is still singly exponential, and factorial time still qualifies under **EXPTIME**.
   - The function `2`<sup>`2`<sup>`x`</sup></sup> is a doubly exponential function. This function cannot be expressed using two font sizes. This function is outside of **EXPTIME**, but is in **2-EXPTIME**.
3. The least restrictive definition, **ELEMENTARY**, consists of all algorithms with runtime being an elementary expression, which may contain any number of *nested exponents*. It is a union of all **`k`-EXPTIME** time complexities.

   - Tetration is an example of a nonelementary primitive recursive operation. The same applies for all higher hyperoperations.

If you are thinking about any algorithm, including those with little practical value, the Ackermann function and the Knuth-up-arrow function comes into mind. This is among the first algorithms known to be non-primitive recursive, also it is asymptotically faster than any primitive recursive function.

Computing a Knuth-up arrow function `A(b,x,n)` = `b` `↑`<sup>`n`</sup> `x` for nontrivial base `b` and 'superexponent' `x` requires 'super-primitive recursive' time, also of the order of the `(n + 2)`-th hyperoperation.

### Two regular expression conversion problems

A *regular expression* `R` (not a POSIX regex) is a template that specifies a match pattern in text. Let `L` be the set of all text strings of the form described by `R`. They are used to determine whether a string is valid or not as an input in constant space; the regular expression `^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$` describes a valid email address.

**Kleene's theorem:** It is well-known that for every *regular language* `L` in some finite alphabet `Σ`, there exists a *regular expression* `R` and a *deterministic finite-state machine* `M` that produces exactly the language `L`.

#### A double exponential problem

From Klenne's theorem, the complement of the regular language `∁L` is another regular language. The DFA `M-` for `∁L` is identical to the DFA `M` for `L` except that the states being accepting or nonaccepting are all inverted. Derive the regular expression for `∁L` without the negation bar.

Answer: This problem is surprisingly nasty. The regular expression for the complement language is **doubly exponential** to the length of the regular expression of the base language. [A proof has been provided on Page 8 of an Arxiv article by Wouter Gelade and Frank Neven](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0802.2869.pdf).

#### A superexponential algorithm

**Definition:** A *generalized regular expression* is a regular expression that also allows the complementaion operator, allowing sections that is not of the regex form to precede or follow sections that are of the regex form.

Letting `¬` as the complementation operator, an example is `^¬((0|1)*00(0|1)*)[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$`, which describes all strings that can be partitioned into a part that do not contain two zeroes in a row and a part that represents an email address.

Generalized regular expressions have the exact same strength as standard regular expressions without complementation, but can be used to succinctly represent a regular language containing a part that is described as the complement of a regular language with a short regular expression.

Your task is to convert the generalized regular expression into a standard regular expression.

Answer: You can recursively convert each complemented expression into a NFA, and then convert each NFA into a DFA. However, the running time of this algorithm is nonelementart `2` `↑↑` `Θ(n)`, since each layer of recursive negation exponentially increases the number of states of the DFA. In fact, this problem still remains nonelementary if Kleene closure is disallowed. (source: Algorithms by Jeff Erickson)